# Combine by-integer and by-boolean numpy slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm looking for a way to combine two index arrays `b` and `i` (one of type boolean, one of type integer) to slice another array `x`.

```
x = np.array([5.5, 6.6, 3.3, 7.7, 8.8])
i = np.array([1, 4])
b = np.array([True, True, False, False, False])
```

The resulting array should be `x == [6.6]` because it's indexed by `i` (`i[0]`) and by the value in `b[1]`.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to express `x[i & b]` with `i` being an integer array. I know how to convert boolean index arrays to integer index arrays (`np.where(b)`), but that would merely shift the problem to combining two integer index arrays, which I also don't have a solution for.

Obviously subsequent slicing doesn't work (i.e. `x[i][b]` or vice versa), because the dimensionality changes after each separate slicing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The resulting array should be..." Can you provide the full expected array? Is it `output = [6.6]`?

Comment: Fixed, there shouldn't have been an index.

Comment: I've converted everything to an array since it makes answering easier.

Comment: Isn't this just `x[i][b[i]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `O(n)` method is to convert the index array `i` to a boolean array and *then* take the `&`:

```
b_i = np.zeros_like(b)
b_i[i] = True

output = x[b_i & b]
```

This method generalizes to all logical operators (e.g. `&`, `|`, ...).

---

A more memory-efficient method is to apply the same indexing operation `i` to `b`:

```
output = x[i][b[i]]

# For the example in the question,
# x[i] == [6.6, 8.8]
# b[i] == [True, False]
```